# Create a bitmap from patch object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bitmap, matlab-figure

I have a set of polygon vertices in in X, Y matrices and their colors are in RGB values in another matrix C.

I then use fill() function to generate patch objects that is displayed in a Matlab figure.

I want to create a bmp object from this figure. What I mean by a bmp object is the x,y coordinates of the pixels and there RGB values.

If I use the print() function, with '-dbmp' and a file name, matlab can write the bmp to a file. But then I have to read the file with imread() to create the bmp object.

Is there a way to create the bmp object without writing and reading to from a file?

Becauswe I have to perform this operation many times and writing and reading to file is time consuming and will reduce the life time of my disk too I guess.

Edit: code after editing according to answer

```
N = 5;
Tri = 100;
res = 200; %200 pixles per inch
G = zeros(Tri,9,N);


X = 2*rand(Tri,3,N);
Y = 2*rand(Tri,3,N);
R = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;
G = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;
B = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;

for c1=1:N
   G(:,1:3,c1)= X(:,:,c1);
    G(:,4:6,c1)= Y(:,:,c1);
    G(:,7,c1)= R(:,c1);
    G(:,8,c1)= G(:,c1);
    G(:,9,c1)= B(:,c1);

end

for c2=1:N;
    h = figure('Visible','off');
    set(h, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 400 400]/res);
    for c3 =1:Tri
        h1 = fill(G(c3,1:3,c2), G(c3,4:6,c2), [G(c3,7,c2) G(c3,8,c2) G(c3,9,c2)]);
        set(h1,'EdgeColor','None');
        hold on;
    end
    %print(h,'-dbmp',['-r' num2str(res)],['file' num2str(c2)]);
    F = getframe(h);
    [a, b] = frame2im(F);

    Tmp_v1 =  a;
    Tmp_v1 = Tmp_v1(:);
    Norm_v1(c2) = norm(single(Tmp_v1));
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the current figure open, you can try the [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) idiom.  Once you have access to this, you can access the frame's image data by looking at the `cdata` field in the structure.  After you have this, you can use the [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) command from MATLAB's image processing toolbox (let's hope you have it...) to write the image to file.

Here's an example:

```
x = 1 : 5;
y = 1 : 5;
plot(x,y); %// Plot a line
h = getframe;
img = h.cdata;
imwrite(img, 'testFrame.bmp');
```

This should be able to grab what is inside the current figure and save it to file.  In this case, this will be a straight line from `(x,y) = (1,1)` to `(x,y) = (5,5)`, with a slope of 1.  Bear in mind that this won't save the title of the graph or the axes.  This will only grab what is rendered inside the frame.

---

## Edit from comments

Now that I know what you're really after, you want to generate a bunch of random polygons, then extract just the core image, without any axes or tick marks and so on.  You'll have to modify your `for` loop where you're creating the images so that you want the figure to fill the entire window without any gray padding  You'll also want to turn off the axis too.  Also, when you're generating each image, you'll need to turn off the ticks.  This is done with a combination of not writing any tick labels, as well as setting the tick length to 0.  In other words, you'll need to modify your code so that it looks like this.  You'll see where I inserted code by seeing the `%// NEW` statements in your code:

```
for c2=1:N;
    h = figure('Visible','off');
    subplot('position', [0 0 1 1]); %// NEW
    axis off; %// NEW
    set(h, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 400 400]/res);
    for c3 =1:Tri
        h1 = fill(G(c3,1:3,c2), G(c3,4:6,c2), [G(c3,7,c2) G(c3,8,c2) G(c3,9,c2)]);
        set(h1,'EdgeColor','None');
        set(gca,'xcolor','w','ycolor','w','xtick',[],'ytick',[]) %// NEW
        set(gca,'Ticklength',[0 0]); %// NEW
        hold on;
    end
    %print(h,'-dbmp',['-r' num2str(res)],['file' num2str(c2)]);

    F = getframe(h);
    close all; %// NEW
    [a, b] = frame2im(F);
    a = imresize(a, [400 400], 'nearest'); %// NEW

    Tmp_v1 =  a;
    Tmp_v1 = Tmp_v1(:);
    Norm_v1(c2) = norm(single(Tmp_v1));
end
```

---

This will still show you the frames being popped up for each image you're creating, but you should be able to get just pure image data at this point.  Note that the images are still coming out as a bit larger than `400 x 400`.  This is due to the fact that once we have removed the borders and the tick marks and so on, the figure will **stretch** to fill the entire figure.  To get around this, I use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) and shrink the images back down to `400 x 400` as per your desired size.

Also, take note that every time you generate a new image, a new figure is spawned.  Every time you call `getframe`, the figure with this randomly generated polygon image pops up, and `getframe` takes a snapshot of that current frame.  There isn't a way to prevent this from happening, as you won't be able to take a snapshot of that figure.  One way to get around this would be to close the figure after you grab the image.  You can do a `close all;` after each call to `getframe`.  That way, only one figure gets shown at any one time, but this still won't prevent the figure from showing up.

If I do find a solution to this, I'll let you know!

Comment: Thanks it worked. But one little problem. my image is set to 400 x 400 pixels, but the cdata has more pixels. I guess this must be the frame and axis around the figure. Can I remove those please? I included my code with getframe() in the edit of the question.

Comment: @user3761729 - Let me take a look.  I'll get back to you

Comment: I tried to select the center 400 by 400 pixels and see if that represent my figure, but actually it cut more on x axis and y had some of the gray area still. So I guess there is some distortion happening in getframe() other than adding the gray area. And also getframe() outputs the figure to screen even with semicolon. I would like to suppress that too, thanks

Comment: `getframe` takes a snapshot of your current screen where the figure is centered at.  The only thing I can suggest is to use `getframe`, but then you can also specify a rectangle of where you want the snapshot taken.  I would suggest moving the figure to the top left corner, then manually figure out where the core window is.  Let me get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Also I think I may have clouded your judgement by telling you my method rather than problem. My question is, I have a set of triangles defined by 3 x,y points and rgb color  and want to create a bit map (400 by 400 pixels) from those triangles all put together on top of each other.

Comment: Aha, ok. So you **don't** want to display the axis, correct?  That's really easy to do, but let me know before I suggest something

Comment: I want to remove any data that is not part of my triangles. The only information is the triangles all put on each other in a 400 by 400 pixel bitmap. No axis, no white margin. Thanks

Comment: @user3761729 - OK. Let me edit my post.  You should have told me that to begin with :) I would have written the right answer at the beginning!

Comment: You are my hero :) spot on. Just one question. It keeps printing the fig to my screen. I think its the getframe() function. Can we stop that too? At least if I can close them. Cause I will put this in another loop to generate lot of random images and machine get stuck after 75 figures on the screen. Thanks

Comment: Actually I tried close(h), now program doesn't get stuck, sill the figure momentarily appears and disappears. Would like to stop that if possible. Guess it takes lot of time to output an image on screen, can save that. Thanks

Comment: @user3761729 - Not that I'm aware of.  `getframe` works by taking a snapshot of where the current frame is.  The only thing I can think of is to close the figure at each iteration.  It won't stop printing the frames to the screen, but at least it will only show one figure at a time rather than all of them.  As such, after the `getframe` call, do a `close all;`.  This is really all that I can think of.  If I do find something I'll let you know!