# Create a bitmap from a set of triangles: Matlab

Tags: matlab, bitmap

I have a set of triangles, defined by the 3 (x,y) coordinates. The x axis is from 0 to 2 and y axis is also same size (unit is inches).

Each triangle is given an RGB value.

I want to render each triangle on top of each other (order doesn't matter) and then create one  bitmap image of size 400 by 400 pixels (as my x and y are 2 inch long, 200 pixels per inch).

My method is given below, but I hope I will not color the opinion of the reader by my solution method. The important thing is the problem.

My method: I used the fill() function of matlab to make patch objects from each triangle and plotted them. Then used getframe() to make a bitmap from the matlab figure. The problem is, I get a white margin around my figure and the dimensions are 420 by 560 pixels. My code follows.

If using fill() and getframe() is the only way to solve this problem, please point out the mistake. I am hoping there is a way to solve the problem without using getframe(). Thanks.

P.S. My previous question was about getframe() [Create a bitmap from patch object in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725408/create-a-bitmap-from-patch-object-in-matlab)

```
N = 5;
Tri = 100;
res = 200; %200 pixles per inch
G = zeros(Tri,9,N);


X = 2*rand(Tri,3,N);
Y = 2*rand(Tri,3,N);
R = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;
G = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;
B = randi([0 255],Tri,N)/255;

for c1=1:N
   G(:,1:3,c1)= X(:,:,c1);
    G(:,4:6,c1)= Y(:,:,c1);
    G(:,7,c1)= R(:,c1);
    G(:,8,c1)= G(:,c1);
    G(:,9,c1)= B(:,c1);

end

for c2=1:N;
    h = figure('Visible','off');
    for c3 =1:Tri
        h1 = fill(G(c3,1:3,c2), G(c3,4:6,c2), [G(c3,7,c2) G(c3,8,c2) G(c3,9,c2)]);
        set(h1,'EdgeColor','None');
        hold on;
    end

     set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 400 400]/res, 'visible','off');
    set(gca,'visible','off');
    F = getframe(h);
    [a, b] = frame2im(F);

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to modify your `for` loop where you're creating the images so that you want the figure to fill the entire window without any gray padding.  You'll also want to turn off the axis too.  Also, when you're generating each image, you'll need to turn off the ticks. This is done with a combination of not writing any tick labels, as well as setting the tick length to 0. In other words, you'll need to modify your code so that it looks like this.  You'll see where I inserted code by seeing the `%// NEW` statements in your code:

```
for c2=1:N;
    h = figure('Visible','off');
    subplot('position', [0 0 1 1]); %// NEW
    axis off; %// NEW
    set(h, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 400 400]/res);
    for c3 =1:Tri
        h1 = fill(G(c3,1:3,c2), G(c3,4:6,c2), [G(c3,7,c2) G(c3,8,c2) G(c3,9,c2)]);
        set(h1,'EdgeColor','None');
        set(gca,'xcolor','w','ycolor','w','xtick',[],'ytick',[]) %// NEW
        set(gca,'Ticklength',[0 0]); %// NEW
        hold on;
    end
    %print(h,'-dbmp',['-r' num2str(res)],['file' num2str(c2)]);

    F = getframe(h);
    close all; %// NEW
    [a, b] = frame2im(F);
    a = imresize(a, [400 400], 'nearest'); %// NEW
end
```

---

This will still show you the frames being popped up for each image you're creating, but you should be able to get just pure image data at this point.  Note that the images are still coming out as a bit larger than `400 x 400`.  This is due to the fact that once we have removed the borders and the tick marks and so on, the figure will **stretch** to fill the entire figure.  To get around this, I use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) and shrink the images back down to `400 x 400` as per your desired size.  Also, take note that every time you generate a new image, a new figure is spawned.  Every time you call `getframe`, the figure with this randomly generated polygon image pops up, and `getframe` takes a snapshot of that current frame.  There isn't a way to prevent this from happening, as you won't be able to take a snapshot of that figure.  One way to get around this would be to close the figure after you grab the image.  You can do a `close all;` after each call to `getframe`.  That way, only one figure gets shown at any one time, but this still won't prevent the figure from showing up.

If I do find a solution to this, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `getframe` function a second argument indicating the crop rectangle you want. Just figure out the boundaries of your figure's region of interest.

See `help getframe` for details.

Comment: It's one option I guess. But I was thinking may be I don't have to use that function at all and instead render the triangls into a bitmap without ever drawing a figure. I don't want to color the opinion by my answer. Thanks.